# Vocal Disguise Effect

Tags: vocals, effects, signal-processing, voice, voice-over

Any suggestions on how to achieve an "Anonymous Vocal Disguise" Effect?
Along the lines of: "Ransom Phone Calls" or "Anonymous TV Interviewee".

I haven't started to experiment yet, seems to be a bit of "Pitch modulation" correction (ie making it mono-tone, so maybe melodyne for this) there is also some pitch shift, doubling and distortion.

If you have any suggestions to speed me to my goal I would really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of apps for this.  From wikipedia:

AthTek Free Voice Changer, Skype Voice Changer, AV Voice Changer Software Diamond 7.0, MorphVOX of Screaming Bee INC, Fake Voice

Or maybe try [Avox Mutator](http://www.antarestech.com/products/avox2.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it on Kontakt